# How to migrate database from RDS in one VPC to RDS in another VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I want to migrate the database from one RDS in one VPC to another RDS in separate VPC. This is not migrating the entire RDS but transferring the contents from one RDS to another and both RDS are in different VPC.

I researched and found a couple of solutions.

First, using mysqldump. However, this might not be the best solution because of the level of expertise needed and a security issue.

Second, I found the AWS DMS(Data Migration Service). But, I read if we want to migrate the contents between the two different VPC we require the peering connection. However, in my case, the migration is from dev VPC to prod VPC and normally we don't initiate the peering connection for prod VPC.

What could be the best solution for this problem?

**Edit:** It's one-off task. The RDS is already created in prod VPC and there are multiple database in it. Now, I need to move the schema along with the data from the dev vpc RDS to prod VPC RDS.

Data is very huge( ~ 600 Gb) with multiple databases

Answer (score 1):

Is it a one-off task or do you need to copy the data periodically?

If it's one-off you can create a new RDS in Prod VPC from the Dev RDS snapshot and transfer the data using DMS without needing a VPC peering.

If it's ongoing replication your best bet is probably DMS.

But it's hard to tell without knowing if it's only the schema or the data too, how much data is involved, how often you want to do it, etc.

Comment: IT is one-off task. The RDS is already created in prod VPC. There are also few database in that RDS. Now I need to migrate the schema along with the data to prod VPC RDS.

Comment: @programmingtech how much data are we talking about? If it’s just a couple of MB a mysqldump snd reload to the prod RDS may be a good option. If it’s a big DB I would use DMS.

Comment: Data is very huge around 700 GB of data. It includes multiple database